# Javascript jQuery run ajax, get response before POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there anyway to run an ajax script and have it get a response before running a form POST.

I don't want to post the main form via ajax. I just want it to work whereas when the user hits submit I want ajax to make a call and check a value then when the response comes back then the form will POST via the browser if the response is successful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to intercept the `submit` event with `preventDefault()`, then make your ajax call and decide if you should submit the form or not (either traditional POST, or another ajax call)

sample code:

```
$('.form-selector').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        // some call you want to make
    }).done(function() {
        e.target.submit(); // this submits the form without generating the event again
    }).fail(function() {
        // validation failed, do someting here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try two Ajax call. On success of first ajax call you can POST your data.

So here I mean to say do validation on first Ajax call call and on Success of it do another Ajax call and POST your data to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajax=false; // form has not been submitted, AJAX not responded
$("form").submit( function(e){
    if ( ajax == true ) return true; // if AJAX response, process form normally

    // if no AJAX response, prevent form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // talk to server
    $.ajax({
        ....,
        success: function(){
            // AJAX successful! change value of variable, and submit form
            ajax = true;
            $("form").trigger("submit");
        })
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use onSubmit method of your  element, as in `<form .... onSubmit="fetchData()">`

Now, make your own function:

```
function fetchData(){
  // send your ajax data and validate.
  return true; // true or false depending on what you validated
}
```